# How to link, and compile, a C++ code using GNU Octave functions?

Tags: c++, octave

I am new to C++, and I have troubles to get going. I want to re-implement a code, written in GNU Octave, using C++. I would, however, still want to use some GNU Octave functionality in that C++ code.

I have installed GNU Octave 4.0.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. My problem is that I can not even compile, since the 'octave/oct.h' is missing?

A simple code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <octave/oct.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{

  Complex number = Complex(0, 1);
  cout << number;

}
```

when compiled with g++ (4.8.4) produces:

"fatal error: octave/oct.h: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type #include  compilation terminated.".

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It looks like the recommended method is to use `mkoctfile` instead of invoking the compiler directly - see the [Standalone Programs](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Standalone-Programs.html) section of the [GNU octave documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with [GNU Octave's own minimal example](https://octave.org/doc/v6.2.0/Standalone-Programs.html), you should be able to compile and run it without problems using

```
$ mkoctfile --link-stand-alone standalone.cc -o standalone
$ ./standalone
Hello Octave world!
 11 12
 21 22
```

In order to be able to use `mkoctfile`, you need to install the [liboctave-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=liboctave-dev) [image: Install liboctave-dev] package

```
$ sudo apt-get install liboctave-dev
```

Comment: Okay, then I guess you should actually use the <> notation to include that octave header file. The difference between "" and <> notation is that the first one searches for the files relative to your current location and the second one searches in a number of paths that are predetermined by your compiler e.g. where it expects standard library headers to be.
More about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename

In that sense: you should probably rather go with the example they give you.

Comment: Hey Anders, I tried to compile it myself now and edited my original answer. If that works for you, too, then please mark the answer as a solution.

Comment: Hey steeldriver, thanks for the remark. I am quite new to this, so I thought I should leave my first answer as kind of a "legacy" so that people reading the comments beneath the answer actually understand what those are referring to.
Do you still think the first answer should be deleted? As I said, I'm not sure about the best practices.

Comment: Is there a liboctave-dev for windows?